# How will handle the user story as part of change request ?

Tags: scrum, agile, user-stories, scrum-master, product-owner

We have implemented a feature as per the discussion with product manager. But there is a requirement change from the customer. So how will handle this request ?

For example : I have created a user story to build a new report - performance report and list in the reports module. However, the customer wants to move and list in different location - say performance reports. So the requirement is to move the performance reports from reports module to performance reports. 
Do we have to create separate user story for this change?
What are the additional steps to be captured when creating user stories ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using User Stories to describe features, then you should certainly continue be using User Stories to describe change requests.

I think the User Story in this case is pretty clear - you know the user, you know the action, you have a reason...

"**As a** user of the reporting tool **I want** performance reports to be in a dedicated location **so that** I can segregate them from other reports"

Then do whatever is the convention in your team in terms of supporting documentation.

I won't touch on how to draw the line between change requests, bugs and missed requirements here - let's just assume it is a clear change request.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a matter of changing the location of the report. It should be a separate story(requirement) assuming the report you build is still useful.

So the story will be something like this.

**As a user, I want all performance reports at one dedicated location.**